# Refusing to install twilio as a dependency of itself

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, google-api-nodejs-client

In my node.js Twilio project folder, I am getting this error while executing `npm install twilio`

```
c:\...\Twilio>npm install twilio
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "twilio"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install twilio as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\...\Twilio\npm-debug.log
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Have you named your package, that is the name field in `package.json`, "twilio"?

That is a [regular cause](https://github.com/npm/npm/search?q=as%20a%20dependency%20of%20itself&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) of this kind of issue. Just rename the package something that is not one of its dependencies.